# Curious behavior of if

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loginversuche'])and (int)$_SESSION['loginversuche']>1 and $_SESSION['loginversuche']<= $maxanzahlloginversuche)
        $loginstatus=$_SESSION['loginversuche']-1;
            {     echo "Test".$_SESSION['loginversuche']." - ".$maxanzahlloginversuche;
            $_SESSION['fehler']='Das war Ihr '.$loginstatus.'. Logixxxxxxxxxnversuch. Nach dem '.$maxanzahlloginversuche.'. fehlerhaften Login wird Ihr Konto bzw. Ihre Ip-Adresse ('.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].') gesperrt.' ;       
echo '<tr><td class="datenzelle2" colspan="2"><strong>'.$_SESSION['fehler'].'</strong></td></tr>';        
if($_SESSION['loginversuche']>=$maxanzahlloginversuche)
{
//  unset($_SESSION['loginversuche']);
 unset($_SESSION['fehler']);
 }
```

>
What is curious? I first asked, if the Session loginversuche is greater than 1, but smaller than $maxanzahllogginversuche. The code within the "if" is executed, so the condition is true.
But, when ging out the actual values of the Session Loginversuche and $maxanzahlloginversuche, it gives out the expected values. The session has 1 and the maxanzahlloginnversuche has 5. And 1 is obviously not greater than 1. I thought it might be a problem with the 1 in the session and it might be interpreted as a string, which caueses the error. Like "a" is greater than "1". But no change. any idea?

Comment: Nice long variable name $maxanzahlloginversuche

Comment: @user2314737 Yes, other spoken languages exist.

Comment: I'd like to know what it means in half a year, too.

Comment: It's at least a good idea to camelCase or snake_case your variables to keep them readable... `maxAnzahlLoginVersuche`. IMO mixing other languages into what is mostly English anyway is pretty bad (what's wrong with maxLoginAttempts?), but whatever works for you...

Comment: Please show a var_dump of the variable in question

Comment: Yes, to get back to the point: show us a ***complete*** sample, including all the variable declarations so we can *see* what values you have and not just take your word for it. Also, some sane indentation would be much appreciated, we're able to help much better without a headache thankyouverymuch.

Comment: Actually: **indent your code in a sane manner** and you'll see your problem! Your `if` doesn't have anything to do with the `{}` block following it.